# Convert List of longs to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

What is the best way to convert a List of primitive longs to an array of strings?

I think I'm looking for something fancier than writing my own loop, etc..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
string[] arr = list.Select(l => l.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is worth checking against the performance of a select statement.

```
string[] result = Array.ConvertAll(list.ToArray(), i => i.ToString());
```